# PHP7 Run Shared Memory (schmop) on XAMPP?

Tags: php, windows, xampp

I'm trying to run the [shared memory](http://php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php) functions in PHp. However when running a script I get the error that the functions aren't defined.

[image]

In order to use shared memory I read this:

> To use shmop you will need to compile PHP with the --enable-shmop parameter in your configure line.

However I don't know how to do this on XAMPP

Comment: What are you trying to do with that extension? IMHO, it's not particularly useful; there are other, much better ways of sharing data between PHP scripts.

Comment: @duskwuff can you list some other libraries? I am trying to store data inbetween execution for scripts without relying on sql/flat files. I looked into memcached but it isn't supported for PHP 7.1 on a Windows x64 environment

Comment: Besides memcache(d), there's also apcu.

Answer (score 1):

In your php.ini, add extension=php_shmop.dll. This extension is delivered shared by default, so it needs to be loaded for the functions to become available.

Thanks.